# What should I change the 'Authorized redirect URIs' to?

Tags: android, cordova, google-plus, google-play-services, crosswalk-runtime

**I am using a Cordova based web-app compiled for Android with Crosswalk.**

---

In the Google Developers Console I have set up a:

> Client ID for web application

With the Javascript origins as:

> http://localhost

I'm wondering what I should change the Redirect URIs to the prevent the errors I am getting, such as:

> redirect_uri_mismatch

I have used many to different results, but none have worked.

In some cases, I have managed to sign-in to **Google+** through the app, but not request 'player details' or 'leaderboards' data.

---

*Here is the downloaded **JSON** from the current settings:*

```
{"web":{
    "client_id":"XXXXX_clientID",
    "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
 "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_email":"","client_x509_cert_url":"",
    "client_secret":"XXXXX_clientSECRET",
    "redirect_uris":["http://localhost/oauth2callback"],
    "javascript_origins":["http://localhost","https://localhost"]}}
```